# Unable to push into Github using Magit

Tags: magit

When I try to push into my remote repository, the mini buffer says `Running git push -v origin master:refs/heads/master`  but nothing else happens.

Following the manual, I have staged, committed, and linked my remote repository.  Only when I try to push by `P p` I get stuck with the error message. How do I fix this?

Edit: I guess it's waiting for me to enter the password but I don't know where to enter.

Comment: What does the process log buffer show?  (Type `$`)

Comment: The Magit Process buffer is asking me to enter passphrase but it is a read-only buffer.

Comment: Yes, you should be being prompted in the minibuffer.  As you're seeing the prompt in the process buffer, I think the problem is almost certainly that this particular prompt is *not* being recognised as a password prompt by Magit.  Please copy the exact text of that prompt (from the process buffer) into the question, so we can see precisely what it is that isn't being handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is an issue with openssh 8.x. Found the fix [here](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3843).